# Cannot get hardware acceleration to work in Chrome on Intel Alder Lake

Tags: drivers, graphics, google-chrome, video, intel-graphics

I have been trying for several days to get hardware acceleration to work in a fresh HTPC build.

I have an i5-12400 (Alder Lake) CPU running Kubuntu 22. No matter what I try, chrome does not seem to be able to utilize the GPU. I am getting large stuttering issues watching 1440 or 4k videos since everything is software decoded.

I've installed intel-media-driver-non-free from the repository. This appears to work because vainfo output makes sense and VLC is using the graphics card (as shown in intel-gpu-top, GPU usage is ~40% for a HEVC 2.7K go pro video)

Output from vainfo:

```
htpc@htpc:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.14 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.3.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileAV1Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

ffmpeg can also utilize the CPU's iGPU for hardware decoding and encoding.

When I start chrome with `google-chrome-stable`, I get no error output, but going to chrome://gpu shows that no hardware acceleration is enabled.

When I start chrome with `google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder`, It shows that hardware decoding is enabled and available, but when I scroll to the bottom of chrome://gpu, there are no codecs listed, and all decoding is still done via software. I'm at a loss.

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Raw Draw: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
WebGPU: Disabled


DAWN Info

<Integrated GPU> Vulkan backend - Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1)
[Default Toggle Names]
lazy_clear_resource_on_first_use: https://crbug.com/dawn/145: Clears resource to zero on first usage. This initializes the resource so that no dirty bits from recycled memory is present in the new resource.
use_temporary_buffer_in_texture_to_texture_copy: https://crbug.com/dawn/42: Split texture-to-texture copy into two copies: copy from source texture into a temporary buffer, and copy from the temporary buffer into the destination texture when copying between compressed textures that don't have block-aligned sizes. This workaround is enabled by default on all Vulkan drivers to solve an issue in the Vulkan SPEC about the texture-to-texture copies with compressed formats. See #1005 (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1005) for more details.
vulkan_use_d32s8: https://crbug.com/dawn/286: Vulkan mandates support of either D32_FLOAT_S8 or D24_UNORM_S8. When available the backend will use D32S8 (toggle to on) but setting the toggle to off will make it use the D24S8 format when possible.
vulkan_use_s8: https://crbug.com/dawn/666: Vulkan has a pure stencil8 format but it is not universally available. When this toggle is on, the backend will use S8 for the stencil8 format, otherwise it will fallback to D32S8 or D24S8.
disallow_unsafe_apis: http://crbug.com/1138528: Produces validation errors on API entry points or parameter combinations that aren't considered secure yet.
use_vulkan_zero_initialize_workgroup_memory_extension: https://crbug.com/dawn/1302: Initialize workgroup memory with OpConstantNull on Vulkan when the Vulkan extension VK_KHR_zero_initialize_workgroup_memory is supported.
[WebGPU Forced Toggles - enabled]
disallow_spirv: https://crbug.com/1214923: Disallow usage of SPIR-V completely so that only WGSL is used for shader modules. This is useful to prevent a Chromium renderer process from successfully sending SPIR-V code to be compiled in the GPU process.
[Supported Features]
texture-compression-bc
texture-compression-etc2
texture-compression-astc
pipeline-statistics-query
timestamp-query
depth-clamping
depth24unorm-stencil8
depth32float-stencil8
dawn-internal-usages
dawn-native

<CPU> Vulkan backend - llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
[Default Toggle Names]
lazy_clear_resource_on_first_use: https://crbug.com/dawn/145: Clears resource to zero on first usage. This initializes the resource so that no dirty bits from recycled memory is present in the new resource.
use_temporary_buffer_in_texture_to_texture_copy: https://crbug.com/dawn/42: Split texture-to-texture copy into two copies: copy from source texture into a temporary buffer, and copy from the temporary buffer into the destination texture when copying between compressed textures that don't have block-aligned sizes. This workaround is enabled by default on all Vulkan drivers to solve an issue in the Vulkan SPEC about the texture-to-texture copies with compressed formats. See #1005 (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1005) for more details.
vulkan_use_d32s8: https://crbug.com/dawn/286: Vulkan mandates support of either D32_FLOAT_S8 or D24_UNORM_S8. When available the backend will use D32S8 (toggle to on) but setting the toggle to off will make it use the D24S8 format when possible.
vulkan_use_s8: https://crbug.com/dawn/666: Vulkan has a pure stencil8 format but it is not universally available. When this toggle is on, the backend will use S8 for the stencil8 format, otherwise it will fallback to D32S8 or D24S8.
disallow_unsafe_apis: http://crbug.com/1138528: Produces validation errors on API entry points or parameter combinations that aren't considered secure yet.
[WebGPU Forced Toggles - enabled]
disallow_spirv: https://crbug.com/1214923: Disallow usage of SPIR-V completely so that only WGSL is used for shader modules. This is useful to prevent a Chromium renderer process from successfully sending SPIR-V code to be compiled in the GPU process.
[Supported Features]
texture-compression-bc
pipeline-statistics-query
timestamp-query
depth-clamping
depth24unorm-stencil8
depth32float-stencil8
dawn-internal-usages
dawn-native

<CPU> Vulkan backend - SwiftShader Device (Subzero)
[Default Toggle Names]
lazy_clear_resource_on_first_use: https://crbug.com/dawn/145: Clears resource to zero on first usage. This initializes the resource so that no dirty bits from recycled memory is present in the new resource.
use_temporary_buffer_in_texture_to_texture_copy: https://crbug.com/dawn/42: Split texture-to-texture copy into two copies: copy from source texture into a temporary buffer, and copy from the temporary buffer into the destination texture when copying between compressed textures that don't have block-aligned sizes. This workaround is enabled by default on all Vulkan drivers to solve an issue in the Vulkan SPEC about the texture-to-texture copies with compressed formats. See #1005 (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1005) for more details.
vulkan_use_d32s8: https://crbug.com/dawn/286: Vulkan mandates support of either D32_FLOAT_S8 or D24_UNORM_S8. When available the backend will use D32S8 (toggle to on) but setting the toggle to off will make it use the D24S8 format when possible.
vulkan_use_s8: https://crbug.com/dawn/666: Vulkan has a pure stencil8 format but it is not universally available. When this toggle is on, the backend will use S8 for the stencil8 format, otherwise it will fallback to D32S8 or D24S8.
disallow_unsafe_apis: http://crbug.com/1138528: Produces validation errors on API entry points or parameter combinations that aren't considered secure yet.
use_vulkan_zero_initialize_workgroup_memory_extension: https://crbug.com/dawn/1302: Initialize workgroup memory with OpConstantNull on Vulkan when the Vulkan extension VK_KHR_zero_initialize_workgroup_memory is supported.
[WebGPU Forced Toggles - enabled]
disallow_spirv: https://crbug.com/1214923: Disallow usage of SPIR-V completely so that only WGSL is used for shader modules. This is useful to prevent a Chromium renderer process from successfully sending SPIR-V code to be compiled in the GPU process.
[Supported Features]
texture-compression-bc
texture-compression-etc2
texture-compression-astc
timestamp-query
depth-clamping
depth32float-stencil8
dawn-internal-usages
dawn-native
Version Information
Data exported   2022-08-16T00:46:14.462Z
Chrome version  Chrome/103.0.5060.114
Operating system    Linux 5.17.0-1015-oem
Software rendering list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a1c2360c5b02a6d4d6ab33796ad8a268a6128226/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json
Driver bug list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a1c2360c5b02a6d4d6ab33796ad8a268a6128226/gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_list.json
ANGLE commit id 53e1711046b8
2D graphics backend Skia/103 b301ff025004c9cd82816c86c547588e6c24b466
Command Line    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --enable-crashpad --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder --enable-crashpad --flag-switches-begin --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vp9kSVCHWDecoding --flag-switches-end
Driver Information
Initialization time 84
In-process GPU  false
Passthrough Command Decoder true
Sandboxed   false
GPU0    VENDOR= 0x8086 [Google Inc. (Intel)], DEVICE=0x4692 [ANGLE (Intel, Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1), OpenGL 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5)], DRIVER_VENDOR=Mesa, DRIVER_VERSION=22.0.5 *ACTIVE*
Optimus false
AMD switchable  false
GPU CUDA compute capability major version   0
Pixel shader version    1.00
Vertex shader version   1.00
Max. MSAA samples   16
Machine model name
Machine model version
GL_VENDOR   Google Inc. (Intel)
GL_RENDERER ANGLE (Intel, Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1), OpenGL 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5)
GL_VERSION  OpenGL ES 2.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.18629 git hash: 53e1711046b8)
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_ANGLE_base_vertex_base_instance GL_ANGLE_base_vertex_base_instance_shader_builtin GL_ANGLE_client_arrays GL_ANGLE_compressed_texture_etc GL_ANGLE_depth_texture GL_ANGLE_framebuffer_blit GL_ANGLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_ANGLE_get_serialized_context_string GL_ANGLE_get_tex_level_parameter GL_ANGLE_instanced_arrays GL_ANGLE_memory_size GL_ANGLE_multi_draw GL_ANGLE_program_cache_control GL_ANGLE_provoking_vertex GL_ANGLE_request_extension GL_ANGLE_robust_client_memory GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ANGLE_texture_external_update GL_ANGLE_texture_rectangle GL_ANGLE_translated_shader_source GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_ARB_sync GL_CHROMIUM_bind_generates_resource GL_CHROMIUM_bind_uniform_location GL_CHROMIUM_color_buffer_float_rgb GL_CHROMIUM_color_buffer_float_rgba GL_CHROMIUM_copy_texture GL_CHROMIUM_lose_context GL_CHROMIUM_sync_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_draw_buffers GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_memory_object GL_EXT_memory_object_fd GL_EXT_multi_draw_indirect GL_EXT_multisample_compatibility GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_semaphore GL_EXT_semaphore_fd GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc_srgb GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_norm16 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y GL_NV_depth_buffer_float2 GL_NV_fence GL_NV_framebuffer_blit GL_NV_pack_subimage GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object GL_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_stencil GL_OES_compressed_EAC_R11_signed_texture GL_OES_compressed_EAC_R11_unsigned_texture GL_OES_compressed_EAC_RG11_signed_texture GL_OES_compressed_EAC_RG11_unsigned_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_RGBA8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_punchthroughA_RGBA8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_punchthroughA_sRGB8_alpha_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_sRGB8_alpha8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_sRGB8_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_WEBGL_video_texture
Disabled Extensions GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y
Disabled WebGL Extensions
Window system binding vendor    Google Inc. (Intel)
Window system binding version   1.5 (ANGLE 2.1.18629 git hash: 53e1711046b8)
Window system binding extensions    EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANGLE_create_context_webgl_compatibility EGL_CHROMIUM_create_context_bind_generates_resource EGL_CHROMIUM_sync_control EGL_ANGLE_sync_control_rate EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_ANGLE_display_texture_share_group EGL_ANGLE_display_semaphore_share_group EGL_ANGLE_create_context_client_arrays EGL_ANGLE_program_cache_control EGL_ANGLE_robust_resource_initialization EGL_ANGLE_create_context_extensions_enabled EGL_ANDROID_blob_cache EGL_ANDROID_recordable EGL_ANGLE_create_context_backwards_compatible EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_NOK_texture_from_pixmap EGL_KHR_reusable_sync
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP KDE
XDG_SESSION_TYPE    x11
Ozone platform  x11
Direct rendering version    unknown
Reset notification strategy 0x8252
GPU process crash count 0
gfx::BufferFormats supported for allocation and texturing   R_8: not supported, R_16: not supported, RG_88: not supported, RG_1616: not supported, BGR_565: not supported, RGBA_4444: not supported, RGBX_8888: not supported, RGBA_8888: not supported, BGRX_8888: not supported, BGRA_1010102: not supported, RGBA_1010102: not supported, BGRA_8888: not supported, RGBA_F16: not supported, YVU_420: not supported, YUV_420_BIPLANAR: not supported, P010: not supported
Compositor Information
Tile Update Mode    One-copy
Partial Raster  Enabled
GpuMemoryBuffers Status
R_8 Software only
R_16    Software only
RG_88   Software only
RG_1616 Software only
BGR_565 Software only
RGBA_4444   Software only
RGBX_8888   Software only
RGBA_8888   Software only
BGRX_8888   Software only
BGRA_1010102    Software only
RGBA_1010102    Software only
BGRA_8888   Software only
RGBA_F16    Software only
YVU_420 Software only
YUV_420_BIPLANAR    Software only
P010    Software only
Display(s) Information
Info    Display[21912278080705859] bounds=[0,0 1536x864], workarea=[0,0 1536x829], scale=1.25, rotation=0, panel_rotation=0 external.
Color space (all)   {primaries:BT709, transfer:SRGB, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}
Buffer format (all) BGRA_8888
SDR white level in nits 203
HDR relative maximum luminance  1
Bits per color component    8
Bits per pixel  24
Refresh Rate in Hz  60
Video Acceleration Information
Decoding
Encoding
Vulkan Information
Device Performance Information
Log Messages
[8443:8443:0815/194612.352964:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] : InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Another thing that might be of interest is whenever I launch via the command line, the only thing I get posted to stdout is `WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots more googling, I finally found the magical combination of search terms to find this post: [Link to forum post](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/hardware-acceleration-problem-with-browsers/24084/19)

Turns out I needed to disable the chrome decoder.

When I launch with `google-chrome-stable -enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder --use-gl=desktop --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder`
I am now seeing support for h264 and vp9 hardware decoding.

However, my GPU supports AV1 hardware decoding. I don't know why I am not seeing AV1 listed. Youtube is using AV1 for higher resolution high quality videos, and it would be great to utilize the GPU for that as well. I don't know.